# How to show one div on click and hide others on click using ui-route?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
my js:

var app = angular.module("dashboardApp", ["ngMaterial", "ngAnimate", "ngSanitize", "ui.bootstrap", "ngAria", "ui.router", "datatables", "gridshore.c3js.chart"]);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/systems');

    $stateProvider
        .state('systems',{
            url:"/systems",
            templateUrl: 'pages/systems.html'
        })

        .state('summary', {
            url:"/summary",
            controller:"maxeCtrl",
            templateUrl: 'pages/summary.html'       
        });
});

app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll, $stateParams, $timeout) { 
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
        $timeout(function() { 
          $location.hash($stateParams.scrollTo);
          $anchorScroll();
        }, 100);
      });
    });
```

Here i am trying to  inject $anchorScroll and it will scroll you to any element with the id found in $location.hash() ----> which in case here is incident.

page1:

```
<div class="system_row2">
                <div class="col-sm-3">Today Incident's:</div>
                <div class="col-sm-9 ">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <a ui-sref="summary({scrollTo:'incident'})">
                            </a>   
                            </div>
```

Page2: i am using accordion here and providing id="incident" which will scroll to this element.

```
<div id="abc">
this is div 1
</div>

<div uib-accordion-group id="incident" class="panel-default">
                        <uib-accordion-heading>
                        <div class="accordion_heading">Incidents</div>
                        </uib-accordion-heading>
                        <uib-accordion-body> </uib-accordion-body>
                                    <table>
                                    </table>
                    </div>
```

Mycontroller:

```
app.controller("maxeCtrl", ["$scope", "MAXeService", "DTOptionsBuilder", "$timeout", function($scope, MAXeService, DTOptionsBuilder, $timeout) {

    console.log("Angular: MAXeCtrl in action")

    $scope.oneAtATime = true;

    $scope.status = {
            isFirstOpen: true,
            isSecondOpen: true
    };
```

I want div id="incident" to be displayed when user clicks on "summary({scrollTo:'incident'})" and the other div with id="abc" should hide.

Appreciate any kind of help in advance.

Comment: when should the div with `id="abc"` show?

Comment: this is not how it is supposed to work. this idea seems not useful. you can just use ng-if statement for this

Comment: @Icycool  When I click a button to have a div1 show and the div2 hide, and when I click it again to do the opposite, div 2 hide and div1 show.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for named views. Check here

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Sample from above link

```
<!-- index.html -->     
<body>      
  <div ui-view="filters"></div>     
  <div ui-view="tabledata"></div>       
  <div ui-view="graph"></div>       
</body>
```

Routing

```
$stateProvider      
  .state('report',{     
    views: {        
      'filters': {      
        templateUrl: 'report-filters.html',     
        controller: function($scope){ ... controller stuff just for filters view ... }      
      },        
      'tabledata': {        
        templateUrl: 'report-table.html',       
        controller: function($scope){ ... controller stuff just for tabledata view ... }        
      },        
      'graph': {        
        templateUrl: 'report-graph.html',       
        controller: function($scope){ ... controller stuff just for graph view ... }        
      }     
    }       
  })
```

for `ui-router >=1.0` check here https://ui-router.github.io/guide/views#multiple-named-uiviews